# . + tab AutoComplete not working in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, methods, pip, jupyter-notebook, libraries

So out of nowhere I seemingly cannot autocomplete methods using . + Tab in Jupyter Notebook.

Currently running Jupyter 6.0.1

I've tried the following with no success:

`$ sudo easy_install readline`

`conda install -c anaconda jedi` & updated conda

and the following

`pip install pyreadline`

thanks!

Comment: Are you using dot-tab in the second line of a previously evaluated cell?  This is a known issue. i.e. if you have `x=1` in the cell, evaluate, then add another line in the cell of `x.<tab>`, it will not show anything.

Comment: thanks for the response, James! dot-tab does not work under any circumstances

Answer (score 1):

`pip install jedi --upgrade` (taking it from 0.17.0 to 0.18.0) and restarting the kernel did the trick for me.