# Jupyter notebook does not autocomplete code for libraries, methods or attributes

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I recently did a full reinstall of Anaconda distribution because of some user-related problems I was having. I installed the latest 64-bit version for Windows 10, and my Jupyter Notebook stopped autocompleting just about everything (methods, library names, object attributes, etc.).

My current version is 7.19.0.

```
>>> conda list ipython
# packages in environment at D:\Users\my_user\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ipython                   7.19.0           py38hd4e2768_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
```

Prior to reinstalling, I was able to press the *tab* key when typing the first few characters of an object/library and the IDE would display a dropdown list of objects that started with the same string. I cannot get said list to display on the current version.

For some reason however, when I type a function's name, I can still press *shift* + *tab* to display the docstring and expected arguments. It's only the dropdown list that disappeared.

I have not been able to find a solution ([despite other users are having this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60066265/tab-autocomplete-not-working-in-jupyter-notebook)).